# HTML no line break at hyphens

Tags: html

So I have the text `e-commerce` and I don't want the line to wrap at the dash.
How would I restrict wrapping for that text line?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the non-breaking hyphen: `&#8209;`

Comment: +1. It works.  Didn't know that.  Here's a fiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/NR5Ch/

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin -- my first SO drag-race victory (I've been an also-ran dozens of times)!  And OP, I just Googled it myself.  If you didn't have success there, you may want to read [this](http://owlet.letu.edu/grammarlinks/punctuation/punct4d.html).

Comment: The downside of that is that searching the page for "e-commerce" will not find the string.

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov - It depends on the sophistication of your browser, yes.

Comment: @Malvolio well, Chrome 65 is not sophisticated enough to see hyphen and &#8209; or &#2011; as the same symbol.

Comment: Beware that not all fonts have that character, so it might be rendered in a fall-back font instead. In some cases, this might be visually unpleasant.

Answer (score 94):

You could use CSS: [`white-space: nowrap;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Example: Wrap the text in a span with that CSS declaration.

`<span style="white-space: nowrap;">e-commerce</span>`

Comment: only then it will not wrap at all which is not the intended result.

Comment: … uuhh… what? `blah blah <span style="white-space: nowrap;">e-commerce</span>` will work just fine =\

Comment: I am adding an example, it's not as clean as the `&#8209;` method though.

Comment: Due to the title of the question, everyone is coming to this page from google searching for this answer, not caring about hyphens.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing that.

Answer (score 20):

Wrap it in the `<nobr>…</nobr>` tag, or if you care out the validity of your HTML, set the `white-space: nowrap;` style.

Comment: I think `<nobr>` tags are deprecated.

Edit: I was not the downvoter though.

Comment: *If* you care about validity?!?  I wasn't the downvoter, but if I were, I wouldn't reverse it on those grounds.

Comment: nobr is deprecated, but it shouldn't be. That's a plain screw-up by the World Wide Web Consortium.

Comment: Hadn't heard of it, but `<nobr>` works everywhere I tried - and better than the other options... It's like, we - never got to know each other... and now it's too late? Say it isn't so!

Answer (score 8):

There is this non-breaking hyphen (copy and paste it):`‑` or use `&#8209;` or `&#x2011;`

Note that this is the only *unicode “character”* which unifies the following characteristics:

- is pre-composed (you can make anything non-breaking by composition)
- is non-breaking
- is a hyphen or dash or similar

The usage of the **word joiner** represented by `&#8288;` or `&#x2060;` allows for other hyphens. Results:

**e‐⁠commerce** (hyphen followed by word joiner)
**e‑⁠commerce** (ASCII hyphen/minus followed by word joiner)
...and the precomposed one for reference:
**e‑commerce** (non-breaking hyphen)

http://jsfiddle.net/NR5Ch/58/   (this fiddle shows the effect of the word joiner)