# Android TextView not wrapping it's text correctly

Tags: android

As you can see from the image below, Android does not wrap my text as I would expect: 
[image]

There is no space between the "-" and the "$", yet they are on different lines. The string is just defined like this:

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello stackoverflow. This text does not wrap well -$999,999,999.</string>
```

Is there any way to change this behaviour? I want "-$999,999,999" to wrap as if it were one word.

Comment: your question is text view was not wrap correctly.

Comment: Yep. It's not wrapping correctly, at least for what I want. I want to know if there is anything I can change to achieve the end result I am after.

Comment: its not possible in default text view.[Refer this link you get better solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290877/justify-text-in-textview-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have the answer. There is a non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;`(mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219007/html-no-line-break)). All I needed to do was define the String like so:

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello stackoverflow. This text does not wrap well &#8209;$999,999,999.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly it is more a matter of text-formatting. If you want "-" and "$" to be on the same row, set the text as textView.setText("Hello stackoverflow. This text does not wrap well \n -$999,999,999."). The "\n" is interpreted as a new line

Comment: Yeah, but in a real scenario the $ value would be dynamic, and not always on the second line. Thanks for the answer anyway. I just posted the solution if you are interested.